# Function template argument deduction and inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, template-argument-deduction, type-deduction

I thought that the function overload with the most specific matching argument types would be called, but it seems I don't understand an aspect of type deduction when template and inherited types are combined.

Example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<typeinfo>

struct Foo {};
struct Bar : Foo {};

#ifdef FOO
void print_typeid( const Foo& f ) {
  std::cout << "(F) typeid: " << typeid(f).name() << std::endl;
}
#endif // FOO

#ifdef GENERIC  
template<typename Generic>
void print_typeid( const Generic& g ) {
  std::cout << "(G) typeid: " << typeid(g).name() << std::endl;
}  
#endif // GENERIC

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

  Foo foo; print_typeid(foo); 
  Bar bar; print_typeid(bar);

  return 0;
}
```

Test cases

**1. Define FOO only**

`$ g++ -DFOO main.cpp -o foo && ./foo`

Output:

```
(F) typeid: 3Foo
(F) typeid: 3Foo
```

This makes sense to me as the objects `foo` and `bar` may be
passed as `const Foo&` and since there is no compile-time downcast,
`bar` must be identified as having type `Foo`.

**2. Define GENERIC only**

`$ g++ -DGENERIC main.cpp -o generic && ./generic`

Output:

```
(G) typeid: 3Foo
(G) typeid: 3Bar
```

This also makes sense as both `foo` and `bar` are lvalues and can be passed to the function that takes a generic constant reference. This prints the actual type of each object.

**3. Define both FOO and GENERIC**

`$ g++ -DFOO -DGENERIC main.cpp -o both && ./both`

Output:

```
(F) typeid: 3Foo
(G) typeid: 3Bar
```

This one confuses me. Having already established that both objects may be passed to both functions, I expected that because `const Foo&` is a more specific compatible type for `bar` that we would have had the same output as in Case 1. Why does this happen?

Tested using gcc 7.2 and clang 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `typeid` only acts polymorphically if the argument has a polymorphic class type.  And neither `Foo` nor `Bar` is polymorphic, since they do not have any virtual functions or virtual base classes.  So both your `print_typeid` functions are not looking at the actual type of the object, just the declared type of the expression.  If you added `virtual ~Foo() = default;` to class `Foo`, you would see different behavior.

1. Only `FOO`: The declared type of `f` is `const Foo&`, so you get the `typeinfo` for `Foo` in both cases.
2. Only `GENERIC`: In `print_typeid(foo);` the deduced type of template parameter is `Foo`, so you get the `typeinfo` for `Foo`.  But in `print_typeid(bar);` the deduced type is `Bar`, and you get the `typeinfo` for `Bar`.
3. Both `FOO` and `GENERIC`: It's true that a non-template function beats a template function and a more specialized template function beats a less specialized template function in overload resolution, IF the functions would otherwise be ambiguous.  But this rule only kicks in when the implicit conversion sequences for both calls are close enough to the same that neither can be seen as better based on the argument types and parameter types.

For `print_typeid(foo)`, the compiler first does type deduction for the function template, getting `GENERIC=Foo`.  So the specialization of the function template is a potential function with signature `void print_typeid(const Foo&);`.  Since this is identical to the non-template function, the non-template function wins.

For `print_typeid(bar)`, the compiler again does type deduction, this time getting `GENERIC=Bar`.  The specialization of the function template has signature `void print_typeid(const Bar&);`.  So calling the non-template function requires a derived-to-base conversion, where calling the template specialization has just a qualification conversion (adding `const`).  The qualification conversion is better, so the template wins overload resolution.

Answer (score 2):

> This one confuses me. Having already established that both objects may be passed to both functions, I expected that because `const Foo&` is a more specific compatible type for `bar` that we would have had the same output as in Case 1. Why does this happen?

But `const Generic &`, when `Generic` is deduced as `Bar`, is a better match (is an exact match) for a `Bar` object than a `const Foo &`.

So the template version of `print_typeid()` is preferred and selected whan called with a `Bar` object.

On the contrary, calling `print_typeid()` with a `const Foo &` object, both version matches, as exact matches, and the not-template version is preferred over the template version.